# ¿Por qué escribimos "acera" si el original era "facera" que luego devino "hacera"?

Tags: etimología, historia

Veo en la RAE que "hacera" / "facera" y "acera" son distintas maneras de escribir lo que generalmente damos a conocer como "acera":

> **[facero, ra.](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=5ZEBvNCSODXX2xsCpgJx%7CBTNsdmJnEDXX2HcDrRvm)**
>
> (Del lat. *faciarĭus, de facĭes, cara).
>
> ...
>
> 3. f. p. us. acera (‖ fila de casas a cada lado de una calle).
>
> **[hacera.](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=Wxy0COOldDXX2JkjQT3T)**
>
> (De facera).
>
> 1. f. acera.
>
> **[acera.](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=TVgatn8uuDXX2M0ztxAd)**
>
> (De hacera).
>
> 1. f. Orilla de la calle o de otra vía pública, generalmente enlosada, sita junto al paramento de las casas, y particularmente destinada para
>      el tránsito de la gente que va a pie.
>
> ...

Conocía el hecho de que **"hacera"** fuera aceptado, pero esta consulta a la RAE revela que la situación es aún más paradójica de lo que creía: la palabra que más se usa y escribe, **"acera"** parece ser la última en la evolución.

Entonces mi pregunta es: ¿cómo se explica la evolución de esta palabra `facera -> hacera -> acera`? Si bien la migración `facera -> hacera` puedo entenderla en base al uso, ¿qué explicación tiene que se promueva una escritura diferente (sin la **"h"**) para un mismo sonido?

Comment: Alguien a votado -1. Me parece legítimo, por supuesto, pero me gustaría saber los motivos para así mejorar la pregunta. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Ya que hemos descubierto el Ngram hace poco, te dejo aquí el enlace a la [comparativa entre las tres versiones](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=facera%2Chacera%2Cacera&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfacera%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chacera%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cacera%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @CarlosAlejo jejeje curioso que aún haya quien use _hacera_ y _facera_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ¿Qué explicación tiene que se **promueva** una escritura diferente (sin la
> "h") para un mismo sonido?

Creo que hay un error al decir que se *promueve* una escritura diferente. En este caso simplemente la RAE *acepta* un uso contra el cual "ya no se puede competir", porque está tan difundido que puede considerarse una norma, aunque en su origen haya sido una falta de ortografía.

Hay montones de casos similares. Algunos son tan antiguos que no sabemos que "están mal escritos". Por ejemplo:

> Árbol (del latín ARBOR, cambio de R por L)
>
> Buitre (del latín VULTUR, cambio de V por B)
>
> Abogado (del latín ADVOCATUM, cambio de V por B)
>
> Palabra (del latín PARABOLA, se dieron vuelta las letras R y L)

Hay otros casos en los que se usa la palabra "correcta" según su etimología y una versión "incorrecta", como en *rugido* y *ruido*, en un fenómeno muy común llamado *doblete*.

A veces se agregan sonidos que antes no existían, y la RAE termina aceptándolos, como el caso famoso de las palabras *entonces, mientras y quizás*, que hace poco terminan con -s. Y al reves, se aceptan palabras a las que se les ha quitado un sonido, como la antigua *augmento* (que ahora es *aumento*) y *trasporte y traspirar*, que son perfectamente aceptadas por la RAE aunque no tengan la N de la raíz trans-.

Y con respecto a la H perdida en *acera*, lo mismo ocurrió con

> Traer (del latín TRAHERE)
>
> Ora (la conjunción derivada de *ahora*)
>
> Alonso (no está en la RAE obviamente por ser un nombre, pero no existe el correcto *Alhonso*)
>
> Arpa (del germánico HARPA, coexisten ambas formas con y sin h- en la RAE)
>
> Armonía (del latín HARMONIA, también coexisten en la RAE)

Y se da el caso inverso en

> Hasta (del latín AD ISTA, al cual le inventamos una h- inexistente)

Son todos casos en los que errores ortográficos repetidos históricamente se terminan aceptando como norma.

Comment: En el caso de acera, sería posible que la forma moderna apareciese antes de la pérdida del sonido de la H. En tal caso, representaría un cambio fonético verdadero, en vez de un sencillo cambio orográfico. Pero de cuando surgió la forma sin H en comparación con el cambio fonético, no lo sé. Hay unas pocas zonas aspirantes que quedan en España, sería interesante ver cómo lo pronuncia.

Comment: Interesante, muchas gracias por la respuesta. Entiendo que el *doblete* se ha producido con `facera - hacera`, pero sigue pareciéndome curioso que haya un cambio ortográfico que no se asocia con un cambio en el sonido. ¿Sería como si de repente escribiéramos "ojalata" y al final la RAE aceptara esta versión sin H hasta el punto que se volviera la más común? Parece algo difícil sin que otros factores favorezcan la introducción de la nueva grafía.

Comment: Ah, y también *hasta* viene del árabe ḥattá, que se registraba mucho como fasta en los tiempos medievales (y sigue siéndolo en algunos dialectos del asturiano)