# ¿Por qué el español se decantó por "ventana" en vez de por un derivado de "fenestram"?

Tags: historia

Desde hace mucho tiempo me ha llamado la atención el hecho de que en muchos de nuestros idiomas vecinos (catalán, francés, italiano, rumano) la palabra para designar a la ventana sea un derivado directo del latín *fenestram*. En cambio, el español se decantó por un derivado de *ventus*, viento.

Aprovechando que hoy en día tenemos multitud de recursos, me puse a investigar en primer lugar si nuestro idioma dispone de algún derivado propio de *fenestram*. Y resulta que no tiene uno, sino tres: [fenestra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HkVC8MB), [finiestra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Hy3UIU2) e [hiniestra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KQ27I05). Todos ellos en desuso y sinónimos de ventana.

Ya que los términos están, obviamente, en desuso, me puse a buscar en qué momento estuvieron en uso, y ahí vino la sorpresa. Buscando cualquiera de ellos en el mapa de diccionarios, viene que ya en la edición de 1780 estaban todos en desuso. Luego acudí al [Nuevo Tesoro Lexicográfico](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/nuevo-tesoro-lexicografico) y busqué los términos, y encontré algunas referencias. El diccionario de autoridades de 1734 también menciona el desuso de los términos. El de Nebrija de 1495 recoge "hiniestra" como "fenestra", y "ventana" como "fenestra" también, mientras que el de 1516 recoge "hiniestra" o "ventana" como "fenestra". Parece que en el siglo XV ya existían las ventanas pero el término mayoritario era *fenestra*. El CORDE arroja usos de la palabra ventana como muy pronto en 1356, y además en un texto que define "finiestra" como "ventana", con lo que me vuelvo a quedar como estaba.

Tras todo esto, no me queda claro cuál de los términos fue mayoritario en cada momento, y desde cuándo están en desuso los derivados de *fenestram*. Así pues:

- ¿El término "ventana" ha sido siempre el mayoritario en el idioma español?
- ¿En qué momento cayeron en desuso palabras como *fenestra* o *finiestra*?

Bonus:

- ¿Cómo se derivó "ventana" de *ventus*?

Más bonus:

Derivados de *fenestram* que aún tienen vigencia en el español de hoy: *[defenestrar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=C22zoYJ)*, arrojar a alguien por la ventana.

Comment: That is absolutely fascinating. As you know we call it a window which since viento = wind may be cognate with ventana. Like Spanish we do have defenestration. German has Fenster.

Comment: ¡Interesantísima investigación! Para hacer la pregunta perfecta, iría bien que su título fuera una consulta en sí mismo, pues si no resulta complicado saber a simple vista qué se consulta. Por cierto, me recordó a [¿Por qué escribimos “acera” si el original era “facera” que luego devino “hacera”?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13600/1674)

Comment: @fedorqui lo sé, lo que pasa es que a veces cuando empiezo a redactar el texto no tengo muy clara cuál va a ser la pregunta que finalmente haré, sino sólo el tema general sobre el que quiero investigar. Así que le pongo un título como si estuviera escribiendo un _paper_.

Comment: Jejeje falta pues un _abstract_ inicial :) Yo suelo titular al final y siempre me cuesta. Muy buena actualización, ¡gracias!

Comment: @CarlosAlejo: otro derivado que se utiliza actualmente, aunque no figura en el DRAE, es **fenestrado**. De http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fenestrado.2150504/ : "El uso común de fenestrado lo tengo asociado a "paño fenestrado", que es un paño con una ventana mayor o menor que utilizan los cirujanos para cubrir al paciente en el quirófano dejando accesible sólo el lugar del cuerpo en que deben intervenir..." y "Este término aparece con frecuencia en bibliografía histológica y anatómica (p.ej. ligamentos fenestrados, capilares fenestrados), y cualquiera en ese área lo comprende."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Según Corominas, `ventana` antiguamente significaba *abertura, respiradero* (registrado hacia 1300), *respiradero de una nave, de una tienda*. Hacia 1325, también *orificio de la nariz, por donde se respira*. Hacia 1400, *ventana, abertura grande en una pared*.

Convivió con *hiniestra* y la terminó de reemplazar “en fecha tardía” (ss. XVI, XVII).

Según él,

> el idioma se vio obligado a generalizar *ventana* a causa de la homonimia [de *hiniestra*] con [*iniest(r)a*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Lcd0E8L) ’retama’

<sup>Fuente: Corominas y Pascual, *Diccionario Crítico Etimológico Castellano e Hispano*.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

En mi país, Chile, en los tragaluces, o lucernarios, es decir ventanas en la techumbre, la apertura o vano podría denominarse fenestración, según nos indicó un profesor hace años.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26186)