# ¿Por qué "yegua" y no "caballa"?

Tags: etimología, historia, animales, latín

Según el Diccionario de la Lengua Española, tenemos:

> [**Caballo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6OPHOdx)
>   Del lat. *caballus* 'caballo de carga'.
>
> 1. m. Mamífero solípedo del orden de los perisodáctilos, de tamaño grande y extremidades largas, cuello y cola poblados de cerdas largas y abundantes, que se domestica fácilmente y suele utilizarse como montura o animal de tiro.

> [**Yegua**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cAUdTlR)
>   Del lat. *equa*.
>
> 1. f. Hembra del caballo.

Es decir que utilizamos palabras diferentes para el macho y la hembra con etimologías diferentes: caballo procede del latín ***caballus*** mientras que yegua procede de ***equa***.

Sin embargo, parece que en el latín tardío sí se utilizaba *"**caballa**"* con el significado de *"**yegua**"*, pero se dejó de utilizar con ese sentido y se utilizó para denominar a un pez.

> [**Caballa**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6Np68M9)
>   Del lat. tardío *caballa* 'yegua'.
>
> 1. f. Pez teleósteo, de 30 a 40 cm de largo, de color azul y verde con rayas negras por el lomo, que vive en bancos en el Atlántico Norte y es apreciado en la industria conservera.

Mis preguntas:

Si ya se estaba utilizando la forma femenina de "caballo" para designar a la hembra (*"**caballa**"* con el significado de *"**yegua**"*), ¿por qué se dejó de utilizar y permaneció la forma *irregular* *"**yegua**"*?

¿Por qué se utilizó *"**caballa**"* (hembra del caballo) para designar a un pez?

Comment: ¡Buena pregunta, sí señor!

Answer (score 9):

Voy a dar un intento de respuesta, dado que este cambio se produjo en la época del latín vulgar, y es complicado buscar textos de esta época en los que basarse.

En la web de etimologías de Chile podemos leer [lo siguiente](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?caballa):

> La forma más común de su nombre en castellano que es caballa, procede del latín vulgar *caballa*, "yegua doméstica de uso rústico", femenino de *caballus*  (en latín, "caballo rústico de tiro y labor"), voz que como el griego καβάλλης, se considera un préstamo remoto de una lengua de Asia Menor. Debió dársele este nombre seguramente ya en latín vulgar a este pescado, porque los bancos de caballas en su mejor época de pesca suben a la superficie y parecen cabalgar en las olas, voz que ha dado lugar también al portugués *cavala* con que se denomina a este pescado.

Así pues, tenemos por un lado que *caballus* parece ser un préstamo frente a *equus*, lo que hace que uno de los términos sea superfluo (a menos que denominaran a dos tipos de equinos diferentes, cosa que parece ser posible si leemos a [Corominas](http://cvc.cervantes.es/el_rinconete/anteriores/mayo_04/26052004_01.htm), que dice que "caballus" era el caballo malo, castrado, de carga, jamelgo). Por otro lado, tenemos un término (*caballa*) que empieza a popularizarse para denominar a otro tipo de animal. Es posible que lo que acabara pasando fuese algo parecido a lo que pasó con [hiniestra y ventana](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17670/12637). En español se acabó usando *ventana* en vez de un derivado de *fenestram* porque *hiniestra*, que era como se denominaba a la ventana antiguamente, colisionaba fonéticamente con *iniesta* (retama), y el lenguaje se decantó por *ventana*.

Por tanto, dado que por un lado tenemos un término (*caballa*) que se popularizó para denominar a un tipo de pez, y que por otro tenemos una redundancia de términos (*caballus* y *equus*) para el actual caballo, se debió dar prioridad al segundo en el caso del femenino para evitar malentendidos. El lenguaje simplemente se decantó por la evolución de *equa* para el femenino, y mantuvo el *caballo* para el masculino, pasando ambos términos a denominar al mismo tipo de caballo con el tiempo.

Como dato, en el CORDE se pueden encontrar hasta 107 casos en 38 documentos diferentes para "yegua" hasta el año 1300, y tan solo 1 de "caballa" y no estoy muy seguro de si se refiere a la hembra del caballo o al verbo "cabalgar". No hay referencias al pez, imagino que por no ser un tema común sobre el que escribir. En todo caso, antes del siglo XIII ya se había producido completamente el cambio.

Comment: También en catalán *euga* o *egua*, en portugués *egoa*, en sardo logodurés *ebba* y en rumano *iapă* (que he leído que tienen el mismo origen del latín ĔQUA(M)).

Comment: También he leído en otra fuente que en latín clásico se utilizaba ĔQUUS y CABĂLLUS para denominar a dos tipos de caballos, pero la diferencia se pierde en la Alta Edad Media y se acaba usando CABĂLLUS para cualquier caballo.

Answer (score 4):

Añadir a la respuesta de Charlie, este fenómeno se llama *[supletismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supletismo)*, y ha pasado varias veces con parejas de palabras comunes con referentes hembra y macho. Se llaman estas parejas [*heterónimos*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KH5wxsu):

**Personas:**

| male | female |
| --- | --- |
| el varón | la mujer |
| el marido | la mujer |
| el hombre | la mujer |
| el papá | la mamá |
| el padre | la madre |
| el padrino | la madrina |
| el padrastro | la madrastra |
| el yerno | la nuera |
| el jinete | la amazona<sup>1</sup> |
| el caballero | la dama |
| el fraile / fray | la sor |

**Animales:**

| male | female |
| --- | --- |
| el toro | la vaca |
| el buey | la vaca |
| el caballo | la yegua / jaca |
| el carnero | la oveja |
| el chivo<sup>2</sup> | la cabra |

**Adjetivos:**

| male | female |
| --- | --- |
| macho | hembra |
| paterno | materno |
| paternal | maternal |
| fraterno | sororal |
| hermanal | sororal |
| masculino | femenino |

Lo mismo ha pasado con algunos [verbos comunes](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/27262/20700) también.

---

1. También *jinete, jineta*.
2. También *cabro, cabrón, macho cabrío*.

Answer (score -2):

Yo pienso que yegua pertenece a la palabra *equa* que tiene un sonido mas parecido a *aqua* que es igual a agua.

Para el pez le hubiera caído como anillo al dedo el nombre de yegua. Por ejemplo voy a pescar yegua o yeguas.

Pero siempre en la edad media habían gente con poder y no precisamente con conocimientos abundantes, más bien con ganas de hacerse los intelectuales complicando el diccionario y por dejar sus nombres escritos en él.

Ellos generaron esa palabra para el designó del nombre de la hembra del caballo y estoy seguro de algo: en esa época los caballos eran como un Ferrari, una mansión o un carro.

¿Por qué al perro, ratón, gato, león y otros animales no se les cambió el término a la hembra?

Respondo: porque eran irrelevantes para ellos, ya que no eran tan importantes como si lo era el caballo.

> Un ejemplo: una camioneta del tamaño de un carro tico pequeño.

Si alguien le pone el nombre aunque sea fuera de la marca y eso se popularizara al final la persona que le puso ese nombre quedará  por varios años y no va a desaparecer, a excepción que se pierdan todos los lenguajes del mundo actual y las bases de datos y libros.

Ya que todo es globalizado ahora, antiguamente en el latín muchos países hablaban en ese idioma y por las guerras se han perdido libros con muchos conocimientos y sin decir de la lengua latín.

Es por ello que si seguiría existiendo esa lengua y los libros te aseguro que supiéramos quien fue ese infeliz que le puso a la hembra del caballo yegua y quien le puso caballa al pez.

Pero todo esto se perdió con el tiempo y quedaron en el olvido los actores, pero no sus atrocidades de nombres de yegua para la hembra y caballa para el pez, que dejaron para mucho tiempo o para la eternidad.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, Carlos. Tu texto es un poco difícil de leer, y además está plagado de apreciaciones y valoraciones personales. Aquí nos gustan las respuestas objetivas, cuanto más contrastadas mejor. Si tienes fuentes o referencias que apoyen lo que dices, puedes [edit]ar tu respuesta y añadirlas. También te recomendamos dividir el texto en diferentes párrafos para mejorar su comprensión. Consulta la sección [answer] para más información sobre cómo responder a las preguntas, y el [tour] para información general sobre cómo funciona el sitio.