# ¿Por qué el español se decantó por "bosque" en vez de por un derivado de "foresta"?

Tags: historia, sustantivos, latín, español-medieval

Muy en la línea de *[¿Por qué el español se decantó por "ventana" en vez de por un derivado de "fenestram"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17669/12637)*, descubro hoy que la palabra *[bosque](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5xAxQKq)* —de origen incierto según el DLE, aunque [otras fuentes](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?bosque) dicen que viene de la raíz germánica *busk-* (que también dio el catalán *bosc*)— es una rareza en nuestro idioma, ya que en muchos idiomas cercanos se han decantado por un derivado de *foresta*, del bajo latín:

- *Forest* (inglés).
- *Forêt* (francés).
- *Foresta* (italiano).
- *Floresta* (portugués).

Y más raro aún teniendo en cuenta que el adjetivo relacionado es *[forestal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IEeNomR)*: "Perteneciente o relativo a los bosques". Es cierto que en español tenemos tanto

> **[foresta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IEbFyB0)**
>   Del b. lat. *foresta* 'bosque'.
>
> 1. f. Terreno poblado de plantas forestales.

como

> **[floresta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I6xH3e3)**
>   Del fr. ant. *forest*, hoy *forêt*.
>
> 1. f. Terreno frondoso y ameno poblado de árboles.

pero ninguna de las dos palabras es de uso común hoy día. El CORDE da 6616 casos de *bosque* (de los que 1184 son anteriores a 1600) por 1558 de *floresta* (de los que 1275 son anteriores a 1600) y 25 de *foresta*.

Se nota por tanto que antes de 1600 tanto *floresta* como *bosque* se usaban indistintamente. Según Covarrubias, "bosque" era "monte espeso de arboleda" y "floresta" era "selva o monte espeso", por lo que al parecer eran bastante sinónimas allá por 1600.

¿Por qué entonces acabó prevaleciendo en español el extranjerismo frente a la palabra de origen latino?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Me ha quedado un tocho de respuesta... Pero el **resumen** viene a ser que (en mi opinión) en español nos quedamos con "bosque" porque la raíz latina *bosc-* ya se estaba usando en Hispania mucho antes de que nos llegase *foresta*, que es posterior.

---

Que venga del proto-germánico no quiere decir que no pasase por el latín:

> **[boscus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boscus#Latin)**
>
> **Etymology**
>   From Frankish **busk*, from Proto-Germanic **buskaz*.
>
> **Noun**
>   **boscus** *m (genitive* **boscī**); *second declension*
>
> 1. wood, woodland

Nótese que *boscus* es del latín tardío (siglos III-VI), mientras que *[foresta](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foresta#Latin)* corresponde al latín medieval (siglos V al XV); es decir, que *foresta* es posterior a *boscus*, y posiblemente también al latín vulgar *buscus* (ss. VI a IX).

En el CORDE tenemos varias [ocurrencias de la forma "bosc*" anteriores a 1500](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=bosc*&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=1500&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000), donde se puede ver cómo en español da "bosco" y "boscaje" (mientras que en lo que parece catalán da "bosch", "boscatge"). Algunos ejemplos de "bosco":

> *Grangias cum terris, pratis, uineis, nemoribus, usuagris et pascuis in [bosco](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=080218%5C013%5CC003O08022018130705712.1200.1196&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20bosc*%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20%7BI%7D0-1500%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto0) et plano, in aquis et molendinis, in uiis et semitis et omnibus aliis libertatibus et inmunitatibus suis.*
>   <sub>(*Documentos del Monasterio de Santa María de Trianos*, 1255)</sub>
>
> *E todos los traydores dixieron que era muy bien. Entonçe sse metieron en un [bosco](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=1&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=080218%5C013%5CC003O08022018130705712.1200.1196&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20bosc*%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20%7BI%7D0-1500%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto1), e con sus espadas e con ssus cochillos fezieron las andas muy bien fechas, e metieron y dela rama, e echaron y a Ssansón, e cobrieron le muy bien el rostro de un muy rico palio.*
>   <sub>(*Cuento muy fermoso de Otas de Roma*, c. 1300-1325)</sub>
>
> *E purgará en el azeyte el sesto e destruirá los muros de Bernia e tornará los [boscos](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=68&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=080218%5C013%5CC003O08022018130705712.1200.1196&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20bosc*%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20%7BI%7D0-1500%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto68) en el llano e desviará de las razones e tornará en uno; e de cabeça de león será tornado.*
>   <sub>(*El baladro del sabio Merlín con sus profecías*, c. 1400-1498)</sub>

Si hacemos la [búsqueda por "bosq*"](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=bosq*&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=1500&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000), vemos que las formas anteriores convivían con "bosque", habiendo incluso autores que usan tanto ésta como las anteriores, en distintas partes de una misma obra:

> *E en los campos & tierras planas se faze mas vjno. Mas en las montañyas & en los [boscages](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=19&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=080218%5C013%5CC003O08022018132713554.1192.1188&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20bosc*%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20%7BI%7D0-1500%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto19) se faze mejor vjno.* (...)
>   *E sy por auentura tu querras labrar alguna pieça de tierra. la qual sea plena de [boscatge](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=20&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=080218%5C013%5CC003O08022018132713554.1192.1188&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20bosc*%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20%7BI%7D0-1500%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto20) o de Arboles que non fazen fructo. Tu deues escojer aquella partida que sera mas grassa & mas fructifficante segunt que auras conosçençia con las rreglas desuso dichas.* (...)
>   *E avn deues proueher que las ovejas non ayan la pastura en lugares que aya muchas espjnas njn [bosques](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=3&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=080218%5C013%5CC003O08022018132331336.1192.1188&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20bosq*%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20%7BI%7D0-1500%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto3) de arboles o plantas asperas & espinosas.*
>   <sub>(Ferrer Sayol, *Libro de Palladio*, 1380-1385)</sub>
>
> *Et ende aquesta çiudat prende hombre vianda pora XI iornadas, car desque hombre parte por la cueua auant va hombre XI iornadas por desierto, que no hi ha nenguna habitaçion, sino en algunas aualladas que se troban de erbages, en do estan muchas bestias saluages et hay grandes [bosques](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=11&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=080218%5C013%5CC003O08022018134604411.1192.1188&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20bosq*%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20%7BI%7D0-1500%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto11) de pino.* (...)
>   *Et quando los tartres supieron aquesta ordenaçion, fueron ne muyt corroçados, et de continent partieronse todos ensemble et fueron muyt luent deues trasmontana por lugares desiertos, et alla en los [boscages](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=52&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=080218%5C013%5CC003O08022018134219552.1192.1188&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20bosc*%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20%7BI%7D0-1500%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto52) se rebellaron contra Preste Iohan.* (...)
>   *Assi que como los orifantes se sintieron nafrados començaron a foyr por el [bosch](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=55&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=080218%5C013%5CC003O08022018134219552.1192.1188&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20bosc*%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20%7BI%7D0-1500%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto55), crebando los castiellos et matando los hombres que eran desuso.*
>   <sub>(Fernández de Heredia, Juan, *Libro de Marco Polo*, 1396)</sub>

Si los académicos de la RAE dicen que la etimología de "bosque" es incierta, sus razones tendrán.

**En mi opinión**, y por lo visto [también en la de Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bosque#Spanish), "bosque" deriva claramente del latín tardío *boscus*, luego latín vulgar *buscus*, y perduró en la península durante la Edad Media con esa raíz tanto en el occitano (*bosc*) como en el español medieval (¿*bosco*?), para acabar pasando a español y catalán.
La razón posiblemente sea (y esto ya es conjetura mía) que las influencias de godos y árabes en Hispania durante los siglos V a XII no eran las más adecuadas para cambiar de *buscus* (que quizá resultaba más familiar para los godos, por ejemplo) a *foresta*.

Answer (score 10):

Hay que tener en cuenta que hay cognados del germánico *busk-* en las lenguas romances mencionadas, aunque no sean las palabras más usuales para referirse al concepto de "bosque" o "selva" (distinción que a su vez es bastante compleja). El germánico *busk-* pasó al latín como *[boscus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boscus#Latin)* y de allí a sus lenguas hijas:

- portugués: *bosque*
- italiano: *bosco*
- francés: *bois*

La palabra portuguesa *floresta* tiene toda la pinta de ser una deformación de *foresta* por cercanía semántica con *flor*, que a su vez es una derivación totalmente anómala en romance ibérico (debió dar **llor* en castellano, **chor* en portugués), de manera que la descuento.

*Foresta* a su vez también es una palabra anómala en castellano, ya que esa *f-* inicial debió haber desaparecido. De hecho nos llegó por préstamo del latín medieval. Hoy en día es un cultismo muy poco usado, y su derivado *forestal* es un término técnico.

Tampoco sorprende que el inglés use *forest* porque la derivación normal del germánico *busk-* dio *bush*, que tiene otro significado, de manera que también lo descontaría del análisis.

No me cierra claramente que una palabra pueda entrar al portugués desde el catalán o el occitano, como dice el Wikcionario; es casi seguro que el castellano haya sido el intermediario.

Desconozco la situación del doblete *forêt/bois* en francés, en cuanto a su mayor o menor uso, pero por lo que he podido leer, que la diferencia actual tiene que ver con su tamaño: un *bois* es más pequeño. Por lo demás, son sinónimos. Posiblemente lo mismo se pueda decir de *bosco/foresta* en italiano (en los diccionarios están listados como sinónimos).

Para contestar la última pregunta: el extranjerismo dejó de serlo una vez que pasó del franco al latín, lo cual debió ocurrir bastante antes de que éste se dividiese en ramas bien definidas de romance, porque de lo contrario no encontraríamos cognados en todas ellas. (Como detalle curioso, en el Wikcionario dice que hay una etimología posible del latín *foresta* a partir de un término franco, **forhist*, que vendría a significar "grupo de coníferas".)

Comment: We do seem to have the rare word bosk in English too meaning a little wood or thicket. I do not have an online source but a dictionary on my shelf contains it.

Comment: @mdewey That's fascinating. It looks like a reborrowing from Frankish, just as *foresta* looks like a reborrowing from Latin. The group *sk* always gave *sh* in English.

Answer (score -1):

En mi opinión *bosque* viene de la influencia de los neerlandeses que usaron la palabra "Bos" o "Bosch" para bosque.  Así entró en el castellano.

Comment: Interesante hipótesis, Karlomanio. ¿Tienes alguna fuente que sustente la idea? Gracias y bienvenido/a a [spanish.se]

Comment: Yo sé despues de buscar información que esto no es correcto.  No hace votar falta votar en contra.  Parece que la palabra más bien viene de un origen alemán más antiguo através del catalán u occitano.