# ¿Por qué "tenedor" y no "furca"?

Tags: etimología, historia

Lo de furca es solo una rápida y mala sugerencia, pero de acá me viene la duda:

En español tenemos la palabra bifurcarse:

> [**bifurcarse**](https://dle.rae.es/bifurcarse?m=form)
>
> Del lat. vulg. *bifurcāre*, der. regres. de *bifurcātus* 'bifurcado', 'ahorquillado'.
>
> 1. prnl. Dicho de una cosa: Dividirse en dos ramales, brazos o puntas. *Bifurcarse un río, la rama de un árbol*.

Esa palabra se me pareció mucho a la palabra en inglés para tenedor: *fork*. La etimilogía para *fork*, según [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fork), está ligada a la palabra en latín *furca* (*pitchfork* - horca).

Entonces, al menos en inglés, parece ser que se conserva la relación entre la palabra para nombrar el objeto y el verbo "derivado" de ese objeto (*fork/bifurcate*).

Estuve mirando en algunas lenguas romances (traductor de Google, así que disculpas si hay alguna cosa incorrecta) y también se puede ver esa similitud en las palabras (aunque no con el portugués):

- Francés: fourchette/bifurquer
- Italiano: forchetta/biforcare
- Portugués: garfo/bifurcar
- Catalán: forquilla/bifurcar

¿Existe alguna razón por la que en español tengamos una palabra que no se asemeja a la de otros idiomas parecidos? ¿Alguna vez lo llamamos distinto a "tenedor"?

Comment: We do also use fork as a verb by itself. Borges story is in English The garden of the forking paths although in Spanish they se bifurcan. I could have sworn this question had already come up here but I cannot find it, I must have been hallucinating.

Comment: Relacionados: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26494 https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18659 https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23081 https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17669 https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/24116 https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26681 https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26384

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según [esta web](https://www.tienda-medieval.com/blog/cubiertos-medievales.html), durante el medievo lo común era que la comida se tomara con una cuchara, y no se incluyera un cuchillo en el cubierto porque se esperaba que cada uno llevara el suyo. La inclusión del tenedor, por entonces [trinchante](https://dle.rae.es/trinchante), fue más tardía, y en un principio se usaba solo por las personas dedicadas a preparar la carne antes de servirla. Su nombre deriva del hecho de que era la herramienta con la que se aseguraba lo que se iba a trinchar, y en un principio constaba de dos púas, como si fuera una [horca](https://dle.rae.es/horca) (que es la palabra española que deriva directamente del latín *furca*).

Más adelante se comenzaron a usar los tenedores más modernos de tres o cuatro púas, cuando estos comenzaron a ser de uso mayoritario. Posiblemente llegaran así de Italia, donde su uso se extendió antes por su utilidad a la hora de comer pasta (y porque allí eran más refinados, aquí el tenedor [se consideraba cursi](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenedor) y se tendía a comer más con las manos). Al haber ya modificado pues el utensilio su apariencia y haberse dejado de parecer a una horca, entiendo que se le dio otro nombre, el cual pudo derivar sencillamente del hecho de que ese instrumento era el que *tenía* la comida (recordemos que la acepción primordial de *[tenedor](https://dle.rae.es/tenedor)* es "el que tiene"). Así pues, el utensilio que tenía la comida era el tenedor.

En el CORDE los primeros textos que encuentro que hablan de tenedores son del siglo XVI:

> *Vna caxa con dos cuchillos, vn tenedor e vna piedra en que se aguja, un rreal...*
>
> Anónimo, "Escritura de inventario, tasación y partición de los bienes que quedaron por fin y muerte de...", 1538 (España).

En diccionarios, en el *Casas* de 1570 se puede encontrar una entrada para *tenedor*, traduciéndola al italiano como *furchetto*. El *Covarrubias* (1611) no provee una entrada para *tenedor*.

Comment: ¡Brutal! Gran investigación, qué interesante